# Polygon area in PostgreSQL differs from QGIS

Tags: postgresql, qgis, area

I downloaded OpenStreetMap data and uploaded to a local PostgreSQL database with osm2pgsql.
I created a new table as a result of a ST_Union function with only one record (for now).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS m_temp.budapest_merge
(
    id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    st_union geometry(Polygon,3857),
    ter double precision,
    CONSTRAINT budapest_merge_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Then I checked the area of my polygon.

```
SELECT ST_Area(st_union) FROM m_temp.budapest_merge
```

The result was `1151156216.758265 sqm` which was weird for me, because I was expecting something around `520 sqkm`.
I opened the PostgreSQL layer in QGIS, calculated the area with the *Field Calculator* tool's *$area* function.
The result was `526031443.36087507 sqm`, which corresponds to my expectation and reality as well.

**My question** is what can be a problem here?
The QGIS project is in the same projection (EPSG:3857).

Also I know that naming a geometry column st_union is not really nice, but that's not the main concern here.

Comment: Please do **not** ever use EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) to carry out any sort of distance related analysis. The longitude (X) axis is distorted to infinity as you move north or south of the Equator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qgis, `$area` is (if defined), the ellipsoidal area, i.e. the true ground area, while `area(geometry)` is the planar area, i.e. highly impacted by the geometry projection.

In Postgis, `st_area` always use the geometry projection, so it is the equialent of QGIS `area(geometry)`.

That being said, `3857` highly distorts distances and areas as you move away from the equator. It is wrong to use this projection for computing distances or areas.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @JGH ! Actually I supposed to knew that. But now I know again!